# How to remove VirtualBox vboxdrv kernel module?

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, kernel-modules, uninstall

I previously was using VirtualBox on Fedora 30, but recently moved to using [Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes) ([review](https://www.lifewire.com/guide-to-gnome-boxes-2202073)) and am quite happy with the switch.  I've removed VirtualBox, but upon booting up my system, I still get a tainted kernel message:

```
vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

I've tried:

```
sudo rmmod vboxpci vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxdrv
```

(the other modules were being used by vboxdrv)

This appeared to remove the module, but after a reboot, the modules were back.

Since I am no longer using VirtualBox, how can I remove this vboxdrv kernel module?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you have any files in  `/etc/modules-load.d/`, such as virtualbox.conf?

Comment: Did you remove the VirtualBox package?

Comment: @vim_usr How did you remove VirtualBox?

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I removed the Virtual Box package using: dnf remove VirtualBox

Comment: @JeffSchaller No files in that dir

Comment: @vim_ usr Maybe VirtualBox package had installed modules via `dkms`. Please check `dkms status`. If you will get VirtualBox modules you can delete it in clear way via `dkms uninstall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveat: I don't have a Fedora system at-hand, so this is untested!**

I would suggest removing the file `/etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf`; it may be owned by a package, so check: `dnf provides /etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf` and if needed, remove that package with: `dnf remove (that package name)`.

As per this [Fedora Forum post](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?303556-Why-is-modules-load-still-trying-to-load-vboxdrv), you may need to rebuild your initramfs so that it's built without the vbox driver(s). Use: `dracut -f /boot/initramfs-"$(uname -r)".img "$(uname -r)"`

---

Specific solution from the OP:

> I found virtualbox.conf located in /lib/modules-load.d/ and provided by VirtualBox-server. After removing VirtualBox-server, then removing vboxpci, vboxnetadp, vboxnetflt, and vboxdrv via rmmod, and finally rebuilding initramfs as written above, the problem is solved.

Comment: I found virtualbox.conf located in /lib/modules-load.d/ and provided by VirtualBox-server. After removing VirtualBox-server, then removing vboxpci, vboxnetadp, vboxnetflt, 
 and vboxdrv via rmmod, and finally rebuilding initramfs as written above, the problem is solved. Thank you.